# After changing the date format it is not getting reflected in the table

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus, date-formatting

[image]

Why can't I see the change in the table???

Comment: Tag dbms used. (You're using product specific date/time functionality...)

Comment: `SELECT` doesn't change any table data. You need `UPDATE` to do that...

Comment: if the date is stored in a proper datatype column, then format is a display issue and not a storing issue. If it's not stored in a proper datatype column - then please change it, so it is :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> After changing the date format it is not getting reflected in the table

Because the **format** is only for **display**.

A **DATE** doesn't have any format. Oracle does not store dates in the format you see. It stores it internally in `7 bytes` with each byte storing different components of the **datetime** value.

If you want to display, use **TO_CHAR** with proper **FORMAT MODEL**. Also, remember, formatting has an **order of precedence**:

Let's see the **chronological order of precedence**, i.e. starting from highest to least:

- Using **TO_CHAR** or **TO_DATE** at the **individual SQL statement**
- `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT=’whatever format model you want’;`
- Setting it as an **OS environment variable** on the **client machine**
- Setting of `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is in the **database initialization parameters**

For example,

**Individual SQL statement:**

```
SQL> SELECT HIREDATE, TO_CHAR(hiredate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM emp;

HIREDATE            TO_CHAR(HI
------------------- ----------
17/12/1980 00:00:00 1980-12-17
20/02/1981 00:00:00 1981-02-20
22/02/1981 00:00:00 1981-02-22
02/04/1981 00:00:00 1981-04-02
28/09/1981 00:00:00 1981-09-28
01/05/1981 00:00:00 1981-05-01
09/06/1981 00:00:00 1981-06-09
09/12/1982 00:00:00 1982-12-09
17/11/1981 00:00:00 1981-11-17
08/09/1981 00:00:00 1981-09-08
12/01/1983 00:00:00 1983-01-12
03/12/1981 00:00:00 1981-12-03
03/12/1981 00:00:00 1981-12-03
23/01/1982 00:00:00 1982-01-23

14 rows selected.
```

**Session level:**

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='YYYY-MM-DD';

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT hiredate FROM emp;

HIREDATE
----------
1980-12-17
1981-02-20
1981-02-22
1981-04-02
1981-09-28
1981-05-01
1981-06-09
1982-12-09
1981-11-17
1981-09-08
1983-01-12
1981-12-03
1981-12-03
1982-01-23

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

A `DATE` column does not have a "*format*". `DATE` (or `TIMESTAMP`) values are stored in a binary format and are formatted only when displayed by an application.

So any format that you see for a (real) `DATE` column is applied by the **client** that is displaying the data.

Your first query convert the `DATE` column to a varchar applying the format you have specified.

In the second query SQL*Plus applies a default format to the `DATE` column base on the current `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`. If you want to see a different format for your `DATE` columns, change `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`

For more details see the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch3globenv.htm#NLSPG204